# HTTP request JWT

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, jwt

I am a little bit confused about how HTTP works.
My question is that when the server assigns a JWT token to a client after providing credentials, the server assigns token in HTTP header['Authorization']. Now the user is logged in and can make a request.
So please tell me if when the user makes an API call again, will the HTTP header['Authorization'] remain same or be changed?

Comment: if you have a token, you need to add the Authorization header with the token to every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header['Authorization'] remains the same.

The server basically generates a token and sends it to the client-side.
On the client-side, the token will be saved in the request header of subsequent requests sent to the server.

Please check this [resource](https://flaviocopes.com/jwt/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes client has to do every request with authorisation request (protected routes )
so you have to set up a axios configuration (https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig)

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'TOKEN'}
});
```

And you have to know how this authentication and authorisation tokens works for this please go through this (https://blog.restcase.com/4-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods/)